# Order By datetime with groupings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following sql:

```
SELECT 
  floor(extract(epoch from created_date)/3600)*3600 AS "time",
  count(*) as total
FROM event 
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

And getting the following result:

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| time                  | total    |
+-----------------------+----------+
| 2021-03-14 16:00:00   |        2 | 
| 2021-03-14 17:00:00   |        5 | 
| 2021-03-15 06:00:00   |        2 | 
| 2021-03-15 07:00:00   |        1 | 
+-----------------------+----------+
```

However I want to get result ordered by `time` like:

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| time                  | total    |
+-----------------------+----------+
| 2021-03-15 07:00:00   |        1 | 
| 2021-03-15 06:00:00   |        2 | 
| 2021-03-14 17:00:00   |        5 | 
| 2021-03-14 16:00:00   |        2 | 
+-----------------------+----------+
```

**What I tried**
I tried adding the `ORDER BY time DESC` clause but got (zeros):

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| time                  | total    |
+-----------------------+----------+
| 2021-03-14 16:00:00   |        2 | 
| 2021-03-14 17:00:00   |        0 | 
| 2021-03-15 06:00:00   |        0 | 
| 2021-03-15 07:00:00   |        0 | 
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Is there any solution to sort my result "properly" (like in the example)?

Comment: Could you please show some sample data and even a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 to show your behaviour. For me that looks very strange and it's hard to reproduce it...

Comment: @S-Man I think this strange behavior is due to the use of `epoch`, `extract` and `floor`. Replacing the construction `floor(extract(epoch from created_date)/3600)*3600` with `DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_date)`, everything began to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using epoch arithmetic when `date_trunc()` does this more simply?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_date) as time,
       count(*) as total
FROM event 
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time;
```

Note:  If there is a `time` column in `event`, this can be ambiguous.  You can repeat the expression as well:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_date) as time,
       count(*) as total
FROM event 
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_date)
ORDER BY time;
```